# Mysql - Convert Point Geometry in British National Grid (OSGB36) to Latitude/Longitude (wgs84)

Tags: mysql, postgis, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I have a data dump (csv) of place names from https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/os-open-names.html

I need to import this into mysql however the geometry co-ordinates use BNG (OSGB36). Does Mysql have any functions to convert these co-ordinates to wgs84 lat/long or is there any other sql method to achieve this?

another option is perhaps loading it into postgis - does postgis have any funtion to transform BNG to lat/long? Perhaps I could do that and then export the data once transformed and load it into mysql?

In postgis I could do something as follows (not tested)

```
select AddGeometryColumn('locations', 'the_geom', 27700, 'POINT', 2);

-- X and Y are the BNG co-ordinates
UPDATE locations SET the_geom = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || x || ' ' || y || ')', 27700 );

alter table locations add column lat real;

alter table locations add column long real;

update locations set long=st_x(st_transform(the_geom,4326)), 
                      lat=st_y(st_transform(the_geom,4326));
```

Is it possible to do these type of function in mysql - basically what are the equivalent functions in mysql. I cant seem to figure the syntax out? The following doesnt work in mysql:

```
update locations set long=ST_X(ST_Transform(the_geom,4326)), 
                  lat=ST_Y(ST_Transform(the_geom,4326));
```

I get error `function ST_Transform does not exist`. I'm using mysql 5.7

*** UPDATE ***
Sample data:

```
 NAME1      LOCAL_TYPE  GEOMETRY_X  GEOMETRY_Y  DISTRICT_BOROUGH    REGION      COUNTRY 
 Southport  Town        333510      417225      Sefton              North West  England
```

Comment: You are using  mysql or postgis ?

Comment: @scaisEdge I need to use mysql in production

Comment: in mysql there is a table for spatial system reference  ..  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-reference-systems.html  and you could check for your SR  ..  (the SR are in EPSG)

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry but I'm not great with geocoding stuff. How would I use it to achieve the transformation?

Comment: Does this cover only Britain?  Can you provide a short sample of the CSV?  (I may know how to transform it, but I can't tell from what you have said so far.)

Comment: @RickJames hi, yes it only covers britain. I've updated my orginal post to include some sample data.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, of all places, [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/st_transform-missing/)

> Answered by Hartmut Holzgraefe in this comment.
>
> So far the SRID property is just a dummy in MySQL, it is stored as
>   part of a geometries meta data but all actual calculations ignore it
>   and calculations are done assuming Euclidean (planar) geometry.
>
> So ST_Transform would not really do anything at this point anyway.
>
> I think the same is still true for MariaDB, at least the knowledge [sic]
>   base page for the SRID() function still says so:

[*This WorkLog*](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=8684) discusses the progress of implementing `ST_Transform`.

MySQL 8.0 *does* seem to have it implemented:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-transform

So, the solution *may* require upgrading to MySQL 8.0.

The changelog for the very recent 8.0.13 says:

> ----- 2018-10-22 8.0.13 General Availability -- -- -----
>
> MySQL now implements the
>   [ST_Transform()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-transform)
>   spatial function for use in converting geometry values from one
>   spatial reference system (SRS) to another. Currently, it supports
>   conversion between geographic SRSs. For details, see [Spatial Operator
>   Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-operator-functions.html).